# Array elements change after returning from a function in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, arm

I have a simple C program running on ARM architecture. We have two global arrays:

```
char RxB[400];
char GPS[150];
```

I have a function like this which searches and finds a substring between `key` and `termChar`. The result substring is defined as a parameter to the function:

```
SEARCH_STATUS findString_chr(char *src, char *key, int key_size, char termChar, char *dst, int desLen)
{
    char *temp, *tempchar;
    temp = strstr(src, key);
    if (temp == NULL)
        return STR_KEY_NOT_FOUND;
    else
        temp += key_size;

    tempchar = strchr(temp, termChar);
    if (!tempchar)
        return STR_TERMINATOR_NOT_FOUND;

    uint8_t siz = (uint8_t)(tempchar - temp);
    if (siz > desLen)
        return STR_OVERFLOW;
    memcpy(dst, temp, siz);
    dst[siz] = '\0';
    return STR_FOUND;
}
```

In my **main.c** I have a simple code like this:

```
do {
    ST = findString_chr(RxB, key, strlen(key), '$', GPS, 150);
    // Some delay here
    // Some other codes
} while (some conditions);
```

Note that the `RxB` value is varying each 1 second since it is obtained from serial communication.

My problem is that, as I know, after exiting the `findStringchr` function, the value of `GPS` should not be changed, because no one manipulates its elements. But when I debug my code, I observe that the value of `GPS` array is still varying.

Does anyone have any idea?

P.S: The **main.c** in more details:

```
    cnt = 0;        
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port,LED1_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);

    do {
        ST = findString_chr(RxB, key, strlen(key), '$', GPS, 150);
        findString_chrchr(GPS, 2, st, 2);
        if ((st[0] == 'A') && (ST == STR_FOUND)) {
            findString_chrchr(GPS, 3, lati, 10);
            findString_chrchr(GPS, 5, longi, 11);  
            sendState = GPS_ACTIVE;
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            HAL_Delay(1000);    
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
            HAL_Delay(1000);    
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
            HAL_Delay(1000);    
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
            HAL_Delay(1000);                    
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED1_GPIO_Port, LED1_Pin,GPIO_PIN_RESET); 
        }
        HAL_Delay(1000);
        HAL_IWDG_Refresh(&hiwdg);           
        gpsCounter++;
        if (gpsCounter > (TIMEOUT_GPS/1000)) {      
            sendState = GPS_TIMEOUT;
            memcpy(lati, "1111.1111", 10);
            memcpy(longi, "01111.1111", 11);    
            gpsCounter = 0;
        }
    } while ((sendState == GPS_VOID) && (cnt != 1));
```

The `findStringchrchr()` function returns a substring between two subsequent commas:

```
SEARCH_STATUS findString_chrchr(char *src, int commaNumber, char *dst, int desLen) {
    char *temp = src, *end;
    int cnt = 0;
    while (1) {
        temp = strchr(temp, ',') + 1;
        if (!temp)
            return STR_KEY_NOT_FOUND;
        else {
            cnt++;
            if (cnt == commaNumber) {
                end = strchr(temp, ',');
                int D = (end - temp);
                if (D >= desLen)
                    return STR_OVERFLOW;
                if (D == 0)
                    dst[0] = '\0';
                } else {
                    memcpy(dst, temp, D);
                    dst[D] = '\0';
                }   
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return STR_FOUND;
}
```

Comment: Off-by-one here: if `(siz > desLen)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass `GPS` in the position corresponding to the `dst` parameter in the function.

In the function, you have:

```
memcpy(dst,temp,siz);
```

This most certainly modifies the array `GPS` when it is executed, so your assertion that *"the value of GPS should not be changed, because no one manipulates its elements"* is simply wrong.

Comment: So GPS points to a specific place in memory and changes each time its contents change?

Comment: Yes; you showed `GPS` as an array of 150 `char`.  When you pass 'the array' to the function, you pass the address of the first element.  When the parameter `dst` in the function is passed to `memcpy()` as the first argument, that's where the data is copied to, so the array `GPS` is modified by the `memcpy()`.

Comment: There are many possibilities, but the simplest is to pass an array other than `GPS` to the function.  Use a local variable in the function (`main()`?) where you call the search code: `char search_result[150];` and then call `ST = findString_chr(RxB, key, strlen(key), '$', search_result, sizeof(search_result));`.   Then use `search_result` when you need to inspect or otherwise use what was found.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not provide enough information for a complete diagnostic, It is unclear what you mean by *the value of GPS should not be changed, because no one manipulates its elements*. Here are a few ideas:

- As diagnosed by Jonathan, `GPS` is modified by your function `findString_chr` if the key is found. Did you not expect that?
- do you observe the contents of the global array `GPS` to be changed **after** the call to `findString_chr()`? You did not post the relevant code, it is entirely possible that a side effect causes this.

The function `findString_chr` itself has problems:

- The type `uint8_t` in `uint8_t siz = (uint8_t)(tempchar - temp);` is typical of embedded software development practices encouraged by some coding standard with very bad side effects: if the distance between `temp` and `tempchar` is larger than `256`, it makes no sense taking only a meaningless portion of the value, `siz` should have type `int` or `size_t` and using the type `int8_t` does not save any runtime space, it is just a mistake.
- The test `if (siz > desLen)` is off by 1. The space required in the destination array is `siz+1` bytes to account for the null terminator, which you do set at offset `siz`.

Here is a corrected version:

```
SEARCH_STATUS findString_chr(const char *src, const char *key, int key_size,
                             char termChar, char *dst, int desLen) {
    const char *temp, *tempchar;
    int siz;

    temp = strstr(src, key);
    if (temp == NULL)
        return STR_KEY_NOT_FOUND;

    temp += key_size;
    tempchar = strchr(temp, termChar);
    if (!tempchar)
        return STR_TERMINATOR_NOT_FOUND;

    siz = tempchar - temp;
    if (siz >= desLen)
        return STR_OVERFLOW;

    memcpy(dst, temp, siz);
    dst[siz] = '\0';
    return STR_FOUND;
}
```

Regarding your problem, Posting the complete source code to a minimal program exhibiting the problem might not be feasible, but the type of error present in function `findString_chr` could be present elsewhere and cause memory corruption. For example, it is possible that the serial communication routines writing to `RxB` overrun the end of this array, which given the global declarations mentioned in the question, might lie just before the `GPS` array in RAM.

**EDIT:** Following the extra information posted, here are additional problems:

- You call `findString_chrchr(GPS, 2, st, 2);` unconditionally even if `findString_chr` does not return `STR_FOUND`. This is a problem because `findString_chrchr` has undefined behavior if the number of commas present in the string is too small.

Indeed the function `findString_chrchr` has problems:

- There is an extra `}` after the line `if (D == 0) dst[0] = '\0';` causing the `else` block to bind with the outer `if`.
- `temp = strchr(temp, ',') + 1;` will not be `NULL` of `','` is not found. You should test `temp` before incrementing it.
- you do not test if there is another `,` when computing the length to copy. `int D = (end - temp);` might be negative if `temp` is `NULL`, causing undefined behavior.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
SEARCH_STATUS findString_chrchr(const char *src, int commaNumber, char *dst, int desLen) {
    /* skip commaNumber fields */
    while (commaNumber > 0) {
        src = strchr(src, ',');
        if (!src)
            return STR_KEY_NOT_FOUND;
        src++;
        commaNumber--;
    }
    int D = 0;
    while (src[D] != '\0' && src[D] != ',')
        D++;
    if (D >= desLen)
        return STR_OVERFLOW;
    if (D > 0)
        memcpy(dst, src, D);
    dst[D] = '\0';
    return STR_FOUND;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment and corrections. I simply added a long delay just after the function in the code and observed the GPS array changing. I will post some relevant portions of main.c code but GPS array is only used in this loop.